# How to display the data in charts using struts1.3.10

Tags: charts, struts-1

How to display database table data in Chart form?

EX. https://web.archive.org/web/20100825030910/http://www.swiftchart.com/examplebar.htm#top

I am using struts1.3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the little information, I can suggest one thing:

Embed **[Google Graph/Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)** in your page, i.e. you will have to use your struts bean to populate the attributes needed for the Google chart API to display your image.

E.g.

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World" />
```

[Getting Started.](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html)